# Is it impermissible to sell that which is permissable to businesses that are impermissible?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, business

Is it Haram to sell that which is Halal to organisations that mainly deal in Haram matters.

For example: A bar owner approaches you and wants to buy water from you in bulk quantities to sell in his bar.

Does selling the water to the bar owner gets considered as assisting in that which is Evil?

> O you who have believed, do not violate the rites of Allah or [the
>   sanctity of] the sacred month or [neglect the marking of] the
>   sacrificial animals and garlanding [them] or [violate the safety of]
>   those coming to the Sacred House seeking bounty from their Lord and
>   [His] approval. But when you come out of ihram, then [you may] hunt.
>   And do not let the hatred of a people for having obstructed you from
>   al-Masjid al-Haram lead you to transgress. **And cooperate in
>   righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression.
>   And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty. (5:2)**

Answer (score 3):

It is generally understood that engaging in businesses doing haram is prohibited. However, if for the most part, the business is not haram, but might be used for haram sometimes, it is okay.

However, this is not a strict rule. This depends on the context on which it is happening. Is it in a Muslim majority place, non-Muslim majority? How is it easy to find a job or do another business? That is why, it is advised that you seek advice from a scholar that knows your particular situation for more insight.

Now, for example, making business with a bar that offers entertainment like a snooker, so that not all people there are drinking. In this case, it is different to selling to a bar that is just for drinking.

At the end, for such matters, one should seek a scholar who knows better in the matter and context.

Allah knows best.

[Source.](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/05/25/can-i-work-for-a-company-that-sells-various-kinds-of-lab-equipment-including-some-that-is-used-for-genetic-engineering/)